# Get SPUser object

Tags: sharepoint, permissions

I am trying this code to get SPUser object but it keeps throwing exception of user not found even when it returns true for `DoesUserHavePermissions(...`, does anyone know any fix or way around ?

```
if (web.Site.RootWeb.DoesUserHavePermissions("UserLoginName", SPBasePermissions.Open))
{
   SPUser user = web.Site.RootWeb.Users["UserLoginName"];
}
```

Can't use `web.Ensure`

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN:

- SPWeb.Users contains user objects that are explicitly assigned permissions in the website.
- SPWeb.AllUsers contains user objects that represents all users who are either members of the site or who have browsed to the site as authenticated members of a domain group in the site.

So use AllUsers collection

```
 SPUser user = web.Site.RootWeb.AllUsers["UserLoginName"];
```